# Batch file to merge file names into a string doesn't work

Tags: file, batch-file, concatenation, directory

I want to make a batch file, that would make <strike>me happy</strike> a long string of all file names in the directory.

So I have a directory:

```
-docA.pdf
-docB.pdf
-docC.pdf
```

And I want to have a string like this:

> docA.pdf docB.pdf docC.pdf

In a nutshell:
http://bit.ly/u1eAHO

Long way:
I wrote a script

```
    @echo off 
pushd "%~dp0"
set "FILE_LIST=pre_"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%i==%~nx0 (                                                     
                echo %%i

                set "FILE_LIST=%FILE_LIST%%%i"
                echo %FILE_LIST%                                                
        )
    )

echo %FILE_LIST%
pause
```

And get this output:

```
docA.pdf
pre_

docB.pdf
pre_

docC.pdf
pre_

pre_docC.pdf
```

Why? How can I get the good one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty well-known problem with batch files.  The short answer is that batch files are executed by expanding the variables in a line before executing them.  For multiline blocks (the stuff in parentheses) have all of the non-loop variables expanded once and then the loop is run.  Your loop body is essentially:

```
IF NOT %%i==%~nx0 (
    echo %%i
    set "FILE_LIST=pre_%%i"
    echo pre_
)
```

They added a feature called [*delayed expansion*](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) somewhere along the way (NT4 IIRC) that you can enable in the registry or via a `SETLOCAL` statement.  Change your script to something like:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
pushd "%~dp0"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
    IF NOT %%i==%~nx0 (                                                     
        set "FILE_LIST=!FILE_LIST!%%i"
    )
)
echo %FILE_LIST%
endlocal
pause
```

and it should work.  I'm away from my Windows box until Monday, but that should be close enough.  If you run into any problems read the help shown by typing `FOR /?` and `SETLOCAL /?` in a command prompt.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I think it will solve the issue. But my god, they should have changed it long time age. It doesn't work straightforward, but I get the idea. I will test as soon as I will get back to this project.